# SQL - find rows that have the same set of values in a column

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table and I want to select all rows that have exactly the same set of values that appear in a column and return them as a pair of a certain column.

For example, let's say I have a table named Table:

```
C1  C2  
1   1  
1   2  
1   3  
2   1  
3   1  
3   2  
3   3  
4   1  
4   2
```

When I run my query, it should return the row:

```
1  3
```

because these are the two values in C1 that have the same set of values in column C2 (1,2,3).

I have an incorrect query below that returns all rows that have at least one matching value in C2 and I can't figure out how to correct it.

```
SELECT DISTINCT T1.C1, T2.C1
FROM Table T1, Table T2
WHERE T1.C1 != T2.C1 
AND T1.C2 = T2.C2
AND T1.C1 < T2.C1
GROUP BY s1.suppId, s2.suppId;
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: What do you expect to see if you add 5,1 and 5, 2 to your table? Two rows of output?

Comment: @michaelBroughton That is correct. That would yield another row having 4 in the first output column and 5 in the second.

Comment: What if you have three c1s with matching C2 sets? You expect three columns to dynamically appear?

Comment: The high variance of the comments show, that the question is not as clearly formulated as it would be required for an unique answer. Here is my alternative formulation on a less abstract level. The table contains two columns `person_id` and `hobby_id` (interpretation - person A has a hobby H). The question is to find all *pairs of persons with the same set of hobbies*. A pair is shown only once, so if **A** and **B** have same set of hobbies, only **A,B** is shown, not B,A. If A,B and C share same hobbies, three pairs are shown: A,B; A,C and B,C.  This is what I answered below.

Answer (score 1):

**listagg** is the rescue (instead of count as commented by @Juan)

```
 with lst as (
 select c1, LISTAGG(c2, '; ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY c2) c2_lst
 from tst
 group by c1
 )
 select  lst1.c1 c1a, lst2.c1 c1b
 from lst lst1
 inner join lst lst2
 on lst1.c2_lst = lst2.c2_lst and
 lst1.c1 < lst2.c1
 ;
```

gives as requested

```
1 3
```

**[SQLFiddleDemo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/16185/4)**

Also be prepared, this works only small data (the concatenated key is limited with 4000 bytes).

***UPDATE***

listagg concatenates *all values* in the group. To get only distinct values (i.e. **set of values**) an additional query with *DISTINCT* must be performed.

```
 WITH lst AS
   ( SELECT DISTINCT c1,c2 FROM tst
   ),
   lst_dist AS
   (SELECT c1,
     LISTAGG(c2, '; ') WITHIN GROUP (
   ORDER BY c2) c2_lst
   FROM lst
   GROUP BY c1
   )
 SELECT lst1.c1 c1a,
   lst2.c1 c1b
 FROM lst_dist lst1
 INNER JOIN lst_dist lst2
 ON lst1.c2_lst = lst2.c2_lst
 AND lst1.c1    < lst2.c1
```

Comment: I dont know if you have a fiddle so I just update with the one i was working.

Comment: The WM_CONCAT function (if included in your database, pre Oracle 11.2) or LISTAGG (starting Oracle 11.2)

Comment: how is this the answer? the question asks for c1 values that have all the values in c2

Comment: @vkp - as the Q was not clear, I formulated my own version of it (see comment above) and answered it. Feel free to do the same:)

Answer (score 1):

As you do not specify, this one will handle the case of two sets of matching C2 values, outputting two rows - one for each matched set.

```
with thetable as (    
SELECT   1 C1,  1 c2 from dual union 
SELECT   1 C1,   2   c2 from dual union
SELECT   1 C1,   3   c2 from dual union
SELECT   2 C1,   1   c2 from dual union
SELECT   3 C1,   1   c2 from dual union
SELECT   3 C1,   2   c2 from dual union
SELECT   3 C1,   3   c2 from dual union
SELECT   4 C1,   1   c2 from dual union
SELECT   4 C1,   2  c2 from dual union
-- added fourrows to give a second set of matches
SELECT   5 C1,   1   c2 from dual union
SELECT   5 C1,   2  c2 from dual union
SELECT   6 C1,   1  c2 from dual union
SELECT   6 C1,   2  c2 from dual )
SELECT LIST_C2, List_c1
FROM (
    SELECT list_c2
          ,LISTAGG(c1,',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY c1) list_c1
    FROM (      
            SELECT c1, LISTAGG(c2,',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY c2) list_c2 
            FROM thetable
            GROUP BY c1
         )
    group by list_c2        
    )
-- only bring back where we had more than one c1
WHERE instr(list_c1,',') != 0
```

Showing the following two sets of C2 values and their matching lists of C1s

```
LIST_C2  LIST_C1
"1,2"    "4,5,6"
"1,2,3"  "1,3"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this without list agg, using a self join:

```
select t1.c1, t2.c1
from (select t.*, count(*) over (partition by c1) as cnt
      from table t
     ) t1 join
     (select t.*, count(*) over (partition by c1) as cnt
      from table t
     ) t2
     on t1.c2 = t2.c2 and t1.c1 < t1.c2 and t1.cnt = t2.cnt
group by t1.c1, t2.c1
having count(*) = max(t1.cnt);
```

Note:  this assumes that there are no duplicate rows in the table.  A slight variation can work in that case as well.

This joins the rows on the *second* column and then aggregates by the first.  Along the way, it makes sure that the number of matching columns is the same in the two table and that all columns match.