# SQL - Using Comparator in SQL to get common data for different SQL values

Tags: sql, join

I have the following SQL schema
**Asset**
id - int - Primary Key
name - nvarchar

**FailureHistory**
id - int - Primary Key
name - nvarchar

**AssetFailureHistory**
id - int
failureId - int Foreign Key to id in FailureHistory Table
assetId - int - Foreign Key to id in Asset Table

*Sample Data*

**Asset**

```
id   name  
1    Pump1  
2    Pump2  
3    Pump3
```

**FailureHistory**

```
id   name  
1    Valve Failure  
2    Fan Failure  
3    Rotor Failure
```

**AssetFailureHistory**

```
id   failureId assetId  
1    1           1  
2    1           2  
3    2           1  
4    2           3  
5    3           3  
6    2           2  
7    3           2  
8    1           3  
9    3           1  
10   1           3
```

*Expected Output*

```
name  
Pump1  
Pump2
```

What I want is to get the name of all assets from the Asset Table that share the same failure history. In the above example, `Pump1` and `Pump2` both have the same failures - 1, 2, 3 appearing exactly once. This is what I want as a result of SQL query

Comment: @dwir182 Here is how. It might not be the most straightforward way

- Create a Dictionary with key as the all failure types and counts and the key as a list of assets belonging to it
- For each asset, create a failure history/count string in a consistent way. eg. FailureA-0, FailureB-3, FailureC-2
- After building the string, add it to the dictionary as key with its asset id as value.
- If a key already exists, add the asset id to its list of values

Comment: Hi. Please read & act on [ask], hits googling 'stackexchange homework' & the downvote arrow mouseover text. Show some research & effort--here you show none. Act on [mcve]--cut & paste & runnable code including DDL & tabular input table initialization. Your request is like the simplest SQL intro examples--why didn't they help? Read re join. What parts can you do? What does select * from join of 2 relevant tables susggest? PS Please clarify via post edits, not comments.

Comment: @philipxy Thanks for the useful comments. I understand certain rules about asking questions. However, this is not a homework question. Its related to my work. As part of my original question, I had mentioned that I could accomplish this in `Java`/`C#`, but since `SQL` is not my primary role, I am having difficulty. One of the reasons I asked this is because I feel this is probably not even possible to achieve in `SQL` as its not just about the joins, but also about comparing multiple instances data to be exactly the same and only then return the result.

Comment: Thanks. Re reading re homework, it's not that it's necessarily homework, it's also that it's a beginner's question. PS What does "share the same failure history" mean exactly? Besides for answering this question, once you have that phrased clearly & without your specific columns/values/strings you can google. PS Anything can be done in SQL. (And probably should--I mean it--as default programming language--only when we need optimization for specific queries should we bother to write anything but a specification of a result, which is what an SQL query or logic programming language program is.)

Comment: PS What exact output do you want? "all assets from the Asset Table that share the same failure history" doesn't actually make sense. Assuming that we know what a failure history is, do you mean, assets that have the same failure history as some other asset?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL - find rows that have the same set of values in a column](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33374246/3404097)

Answer (score 0):

```
select
   asset.name
from
   assetfailurehistory asfh
   inner join asset on asset.id = asfh.assetid 
 where
   asfh.failureid in (1,2,3);
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that's not the right solution. In my sample table, I only have 4 assets which have the exact same history. However, this query returns me a whole lot more assets

Comment: How do i know you have `4` assets? provide the sample data and more info about your question like condition or else.. My answer are just simple and basic to your question..

Comment: I have updated the question with the sample data and sample output

Comment: Running this on the above sample code, my output is 10 rows, one for each `AssetFailureHistory` entry. I feel what I am trying to achieve may not be possible in `SQL` at all